# Why can I connect TLSv1 if OpenSSL only support SSLv2 and SSLv3?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am using openssl-0.9.8e-7.el5.

openssl ciphers -v shows support only for SSLv2 and SSLv3 cipher types.

However, if I test this connection using tls 1.0 it connects successfully:

openssl s_client -connect hostname:15000 -tls1

```
 CONNECTED(00000003)
 SSL handshake has read 2136 bytes and written 413 bytes
...
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Compression: zlib compression
Expansion: zlib compression
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : AES256-SHA
```

How does it show Protocol is TLSv1 yet OpenSSL itself only supports SSL 3 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSLv3 cipher suites are usable with protocol versions SSLv3 and up, i.e also TLS1.x. The version of the cipher suite only tells you the minimal protocol version.

This also means that if you disable SSLv3 and SSLv2 ciphers suites you effectively disable not only SSLv3 but also TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1, since new cipher suites were only introduced with TLS 1.2.

Comment: So even though TLSv1 was specified, it's falling back to SSLv3 without that being listed? Is this related to TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV not being available in OpenSSL 0.98?

Comment: Protocol and ciphers are different things. It is using the protocol TLS 1.0  as shown with a cipher suite defined for SSL 3.0 and later protocol versions. TLS 1.0 is internally SSL 3.1, but the official name was changed from SSL to TLS.

Comment: And what if SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 and SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 is set while OpenSSL only allows SSLv2 and SSLv3? Would that mean that only TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 would be allowed?

Comment: If NO_SSLv[23] is set then it can do all TLS1.+ which are supported by this specific implementation. In case of OpenSSL  0.9.8 this would mean only TLS1.0 since newer protocol versions are only supported by newer OpenSSL versions.

Comment: So the fact that openssl ciphers -v lists ONLY SSLv2 and SSLv3 protocols, not TLSv1 protocols is confusing since it's possible to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 while allowing TLS1.x.

Comment: Yes, it is confusing if one is not aware that negotiation of the cipher and negotiation of the protocol are different things and that you can use ciphers defined for SSL 3.0 with TLS 1.+ too. But lots of things in SSL/TLS are confusing, it is not an easy to understand protocol.